# Lua - Camera movement, calculating Z

Tags: lua, camera

I'm having a mathematical issue that I can't get through.

I'm making a model browser in Lua where mouse movement is hooked to camera position, camera position has 2 modes: fixed and free, free works flawlessly whereas fixed seems to have issue with calculating proper Z.

X and Y is calculated properly and works without any issue, but Z seems to scale with X, Y way too much as seen here: http://puu.sh/oTN1v/5846343f82.webm (These camera warps happen whenever I click right mouse button, which happens even if I don't move mouse )

```
function self:RightMouseClick()
local cx, cy = mousepos()
local radius = math.sqrt( math.pow( campos.x, 2 ) + math.pow( campos.y, 2 ) )
local ang = ( camorigin - campos ):Angle()

function self:Think()
    if input.IsMouseDown( MOUSE_RIGHT ) then
        local x = camorigin.x + radius * math.cos( math.rad( 1 ) * ( 180 + ang.yaw + ( cx - mousex() ) * 0.5 ) )
        local y = camorigin.y + radius * math.sin( math.rad( 1 ) * ( 180 + ang.yaw + ( cx - mousex() ) * 0.5 ) )
        local z = camorigin.z + radius * math.sin( math.rad( 1 ) * ( ang.pitch + ( cy - mousey() ) * 0.5 ) )

        campos = Vector( x, y, z )
    end
end
```

end

**@Edit: If you have no clue what this code means, you might aswell just tell me how to properly calculate Z for camera movement around axis**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing camorigin from calculation of x, y, z worked out.

Comment: Thanks for remembering to answer your own question. Please remember to mark is as accepted when you can.